# Cordova Android app errors from Google developer console

Tags: android, cordova

Is there anything you can do about crash report errors of your Cordova android app?

My mobile app (consisting of a single page html, css, and javasript) was compiled with Cordova into an android app.

I didn't write a single line of Java code for the app, so what do I do with errors like these below?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1620)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:183)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:135)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query (ContentProviderNative.java:421)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:493)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:435)
at org.chromium.base.ContentUriUtils.getDisplayName (ContentUriUtils.java:59)
at org.chromium.android_webview.AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter$GetDisplayNameTask.doInBackground (AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter.java:17)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't written a single line of Java, but I can assure others did.

First, please provide the following data to help you out:

> How did you create the app? Under what environment? what is your
>   cordova CLI version and cordova-android version? what is the device
>   that shows this error (in Google Console)? what plugins did you
>   install, if any? what versions are those plugins? did you run the app
>   in a device in debug mode and got no errors?

In most cases these cryptic Google console Java errors are caused by plugins, or obsolete cordova and cordova-android versions. I advice you to rebuld your app with at least Cordova 7.1.0 and cordova-android 6.4.0 or newer. If you are instead using Cordova 8, then downgrade to Cordova 7 and see if the error is gone.

With Cordova, there is the classic issue where using an old version is bad, but using the latest one could be worse in some cases, so you should stay with a version in between (neither obsolete nor latest).

Comment: The app was created with Cordova version 7 on Windows 10. I don't think I added any plugin (from config.xml I don't see anything that resembles a plugin). The crashes come from actual phones. For the errors above, the android phone affected is: Xiaomi MI MAX (hydrogen), 2048MB RAM, Android 6.0
When I said I didn't write a single line of the Java code, I meant to say, because of that, I have no control over those errors.